# Delete a row from sqlite table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am deleting a row from sqlite table and row is not doing delete where i am doing wrong 
please suggest me.

```
public void deleteBName(String id) 
    {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
        db.delete(EmergencyTable, colID + "=" + id, null);
    }
```

Comment: do you get any Exception, like SqlliteException :table not exist  or something else,, post logcat as well..

Comment: not i am not getting any exception..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your EmergencyTable or colID  is wrong....

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 //---deletes a particular title---
public boolean deleteTitle(String name) 
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NAME + "=" + name, null) > 0;
}
```

--

```
public void deleteBName(String id) 
    {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
        return db.delete(EmergencyTable, colID + "=" + id, null);
    }
```